# Why do printf and isnan disagree whether a long double value is a NaN?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, clang

Consider the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  __uint128_t n = (__uint128_t(0x00007ffff7dd6e65ULL) << 64) |
                               0x63696c400a2d2d21ULL;
  long double d = 0;
  memcpy(&d, &n, sizeof(long double));
  printf("%d\n", isnan(d));
  printf("%Le\n", d);
}
```

When compiled with clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) and run on macOS it produces the following output:

```
1
3.345927e+3575
```

Why does `isnan` reports this `long double` as NaN while `printf` prints it as `3.345927e+3575`?

Same happens with iostreams and clang++:

```
std::cout << d; // prints 3.34593e+3575
```

Specifically, why is there is a difference in behavior between different C and C++ APIs when handling this number (which appears to be [unnormal extended precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision))?

Comment: What is the underlying type of `long double`? 80-bit x87?

Comment: sizeof(long double) is 16 but I think it's supposed to be 80-bit extended precision FP.

Comment: For me the behavior changes with `-O3`, so probably undefined behavior. With `gcc -O0` it prints "1
nan", with `gcc -O3` it prints "0
2.611193e-4932"

Comment: @EricPostpischil Whether or not `isnan` is a macro seems to depend on which language is being used (according to cppreference, at least). This question is tagged with both C and C++. For C, [`isnan` is a macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan), but for C++ [`isnan` is an overloaded function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan). Given the lack of C++ features in the code, perhaps the C++ tag should be removed?

Comment: @JaMiT: Sure. Regardless, there is no conversion from a `long double` argument of `isnan` to `double`.

Comment: The same behavior happens in C and C++

Comment: Regardless of whether the behavior occurs in C and C++, you should not spam language tags as it consumes the attention of additional people unnecessarily, and the behavior is, as seen, not dependent on the language. Combining language tags should be reserved for asking questions about differences or interactions between languages. For this question, both the C and C++ tags could be omitted.

Comment: I don't think this is how language tags are used in practice as one can see even from a cursory look at the tagged questions.

Comment: Looking at the language tag page for C++ and the info about when to use the tags, I would also recommend removing the c++ tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: it print 1, nan in centos8 & gcc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The object formed by the initialization from the 128-bit integer is invalid because its explicit significand bit does not match the other bits.

Apple Clang is using Intel’s 80-bit floating-point format. According to *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual* (December 2017) 4.2.2, the “Integer” bit is explicitly set to 1 for infinities, normal numbers, and NaNs and to 0 for subnormals and zeros. The Integer<sup>1</sup> bit is the leading bit of the significand, bit 63 in the encoding.

The 64 bits of the significand are in the lower bits of the 128-bit integer, and the code in the question sets them to 63696c400A2D2D21<sub>16</sub>. In this, bit 63 is 0 (the high digit, 6, is 0110<sub>2</sub>). Since the exponent field is 6E65<sub>16</sub> (in bits 79 to 64), this should be a normal number, so bit 63 should be 1.

I do not see a specification of the behavior when the Integer bit is improperly set, so we may expect it is not defined. (One might wonder whether this is intentional behavior of `isnan`, as it is “correctly” reporting that an invalid encoding is not a number.)

When `0x6369…` is corrected to `0xE369…`, the program correctly reports the value is not a NaN.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> So-called because the significand is commonly represented as *b*.*bbb*…*bbb*, where the leading bit is the only one left of the radix point and hence is the only bit representing an integer value. The remaining bits of the significand are fraction bits.